# Opening menu out of threaded Tk instance in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

When I try to run that code the right-click menu inside the list won't open.
If I take the window out of the thread it will work' but in my implementation of that class it must be in a thread.

Moving the window out of thread is working but I need it inside it for other function.

```
from Tkinter import *
from threading import *



class scrollbar_list:
    def __init__(self, frame, title):
        self.selected_item = ''
        self.colored = {}
        self.search_list = []
        self.full_list = []
        self.frame = frame
        self.title = Label(frame, text=title).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')

        self.search_frame = Frame(frame)
        self.search_frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')

        self.search_entry = Entry(self.search_frame, width=26)
        self.search_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.search_button = Button(self.search_frame, text='Search', width=9, command=self.search)
        self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='E')
        self.search_entry.bind('<Return>', self.start_search)

        self.listbox_Frame = Frame(self.frame)
        self.listbox_Frame.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.listbox_Frame)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NS")
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.listbox_Frame, width=35)
        self.listbox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NS")

        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.build_menu()

    def refresh(self):
        self.full_list.sort()
        self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        self.search_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        for line in self.full_list:
            self.listbox.insert(END, line)
        self.color_Table()

    def set_color(self, ITEM, COLOR):
        self.colored[ITEM] = {'bg': COLOR}

    def un_color(self, ITEM):
        self.colored.pop(ITEM, None)

    def color_Table(self):
        for item in self.colored:
            self.listbox.itemconfig(self.listbox.get(0, END).index(item), self.colored[item])

    def contain(self, query):
        for line in self.listbox.get(0, END):
            if query == line:
                return True
        return False

    def get_item(self, item):
        target = self.listbox.get(item)
        return target

    def insert(self, line):
        self.listbox.insert(END, line)
        self.full_list.append(line)
        self.sort()

    def remove(self, item):
        target = self.listbox.get(item)
        self.listbox.delete(item)
        for line in self.full_list:
            if line == target:
                self.full_list.remove(line)
        self.sort()

    def sort(self):
        self.list = []
        self.full_list.sort()
        for line in self.listbox.get(0, END):
            self.list.append(line)
        self.list.sort()
        self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        for line in self.list:
            self.listbox.insert(END, line)

    def start_search(self, EVENT):
        self.search()

    def search(self):
        query = self.search_entry.get()
        list = []
        for line in self.listbox.get(0, END):
            self.list.append(line)
            if query.lower() in line.lower():
                list.insert(0, line)
        list.sort()
        self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        for line in list:
            self.listbox.insert(END, line)
        self.search_entry.delete(0, 'end')

    def double_Click_Enable(self, FUNCTION):
        self.listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", FUNCTION)

    def build_menu(self):
        self.right_click_menu = Menu(self.listbox, tearoff=0)
        self.listbox.bind("<Button-3>", self.right_click_menu_bind)
        self.right_click_menu.add_command(label="refresh", command=self.refresh)

    def right_click_menu_bind(self, event):
        try:
            self.right_click_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
            try:
                self.selected_item = self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection())
            except:
                pass
        finally:
            self.right_click_menu.grab_release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main=Tk()
    list=scrollbar_list(main,'hello')
    for i in range(101):
        list.insert('line -{}'.format(i))
    thread = Thread(target=main.mainloop)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

all other functions work properly except the menu that is not opening so all I need is to find a way to open it

**EDIT:**

Resolved, thank you Nullman that was really a great solution I really didn't think to run it like this for some reason

Comment: probably in most GUI frameworks you have to run all GUI in one thread (mostly in main thread). If you have to run something in another thread then it can't be GUI element. You can only make calculations in thread and use `queue` to send result to main thread which will update GUI. The same way you can use queue to send data from GUI to thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Tk in one thread but run it in another. make a function that will start the whole thing and use that in the thread, like so:

```
def run():
    main = Tk()
    list = scrollbar_list(main, 'hello')
    for i in range(101):
        list.insert('line -{}'.format(i))
    main.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```